# Arangodb response of AQL slow

Tags: arangodb

when i do nested query like this

```
FOR f in friends 
  FOR l in locations 
     FILTER l.friends_id == f.id
RETURN {'friends':f, 'locations':l}
```

(3484 results).

the response is slow (between 7 to 10 seconds) return results via the web interface and arangosh

My concern: this response time is not too big? the production database will much greater than that, and can bring performance problems.

Any idea? 
Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried the following:

```
arangosh [_system]> db._create("users");
[ArangoCollection 1252513721, "users" (type document, status loaded)]

arangosh [_system]> db._create("locations");
[ArangoCollection 1252644793, "locations" (type document, status loaded)]

arangosh [_system]> db._query("FOR i IN 1 .. 10000 INSERT { 'id': i, 'name': 'Name' } INTO users").toArray()
[ ]

arangosh [_system]> db._query("FOR i IN 1 .. 10000 INSERT { 'friends_id': i, 'name': 'Name' } INTO  locations").toArray()
[ ]

arangosh [_system]> db.locations.ensureHashIndex("friends_id")

var a = db._query("FOR f IN users FOR l IN locations FILTER l.friends_id == f.id RETURN { 'u': f, 'l': l}")
```

This will return 1000 records quite fast.

Can you execute the "ensureHashIndex" and try again? Is it now faster?

Comment: The "friend_id" was not indexed! after to execute "ensureHashIndex" the problem was solved,Thanks!